# Finding the $UL$ decomposition of a matrix. (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Find the $A=UL$ decomposition of the following matrix.(Note the letters $UL$)

$$
A =
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
a & b+c & b \\
b & b+c& b \\
c & c & b
\end{array} } \right]
$$

To find $L$ i took the first row subtract the second row to get $
 =
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
a-b & 0 & 0 \\
b & b+c& b \\
c & c & b
\end{array} } \right]
$

Next, I took the second row and subtract the third row from it to get $
 =
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
a-b & 0 & 0 \\
b-c & b& 0 \\
c & c & b
\end{array} } \right]
$.   Hence  $$
 L=
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
a-b & 0 & 0 \\
b-c & b& 0 \\
c & c & b
\end{array} } \right]
$$ Form $L$ i found my $U$ to be 
$$
U =
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1& 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array} } \right]
$$

Is my working correct. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: I'm sure you know how to multiply matrices (it's easy to confirm the result), so what are you asking here really?

Comment: Your solution is correct. To be perfectly honest I don't think I understand what kind of answer you expect.

Comment: Oh Thanks. I thought im wrong

Answer (score -1):

I see what you've done but I think the top right entry of your upper triangular matrix should be zero, since you're not really subtracting the third row from the first right?